# Displaying all Articles Created by a User Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model, devise, controller

Using devise on my rails 4 app.

I would like users to be able to view the articles that they've created, inside of the devise edit registration page.

I have tried lots of different things in order to get this to work, but cannot. Any help would be awesome. Here is my code so far:

registrations_controller.rb (had to manually create this inside of controllers/users):

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def articles
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @articles = @user.articles
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations" }
```

user.rb:

```
has_many :articles
```

article.rb:

```
belongs_to :user
```

edit.html.erb (inside of views/devise/registrations):

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
  <%= article.inspect %>
<% end %>
```

Still new to rails but any help on what I might be doing wrong and/or the best way to go about this would be great. Let me know if you need any other of my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to add `)` at last.
See this,

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Oops, you are 100% correct. Feel a little dumb. Now getting an error on my view `undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass` Thank you for your help :)